# adding back removed li's from the flexslider

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am building a website with a lot of images(about 800). I am using flexslider and that also works great. But if i want to watch it on a phone, everything is working very slow, so i thought to reduce the number of images, this is what i came up with.
HTML

```
<div class="engbikesWrapper">

    <div id="slider" class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li><img src="assets/img/engbikesPics/001.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="assets/img/engbikesPics/002.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="assets/img/engbikesPics/003.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="assets/img/engbikesPics/004.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="assets/img/engbikesPics/005.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="assets/img/engbikesPics/006.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="assets/img/engbikesPics/007.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="assets/img/engbikesPics/008.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="assets/img/engbikesPics/009.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="assets/img/engbikesPics/010.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="assets/img/engbikesPics/011.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="assets/img/engbikesPics/012.jpg" /></li>
       </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li><img src="assets/img/engbikesPics/001.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="assets/img/engbikesPics/002.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="assets/img/engbikesPics/003.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="assets/img/engbikesPics/004.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="assets/img/engbikesPics/005.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="assets/img/engbikesPics/006.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="assets/img/engbikesPics/007.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="assets/img/engbikesPics/008.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="assets/img/engbikesPics/009.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="assets/img/engbikesPics/010.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="assets/img/engbikesPics/011.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="assets/img/engbikesPics/012.jpg" /></li>

      </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

and this is the Jquery:

```
if($(window).width()<400){
    $("#slider .slides li:odd").remove();
    $("#carousel .slides li:odd").remove();
 }
```

this is al working like it should be.
But how can put back the removed LI's when the browser size is bigger than 400px?
Hope to hear from you.

Wim

Comment: Don't use `remove()` instead use `hide()` or `toggle()` ..... And maybe I suggest the use of mediaqueries instead of that script.

Comment: will hide() make it watching on a phone faster? and if i use a media guerie, how would i do that?

Comment: Give a look at _$.detach()_ too: http://api.jquery.com/detach/

Answer (score 0):

You can try just [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) the objects:

---

```
var myObjects = $("#slider, #carousel").find("li:odd");

if($(window).width()<400){
    myObjects.hide();
}

/* and to display when you want */
myObjects.show();
```

---

Answer (score -1):

```
var mql = window.matchMedia("screen and (max-width: 400px)")
if (mql.matches){ // if media query matches
   $("#slider .slides li:odd").remove();
   $("#carousel .slides li:odd").remove();
}
```